# while building the next js 13 app it gives fetch failed error and also prerendering error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13, prerender

[image]

the above error is shown while building the next js 13 app
following is the github repo [github link](https://github.com/sahilkhalidsolkar/personal-portfolio)

and while deploying the app in vercel it shows this error[image][image]

i have also tried adding the error component but still it does not works
please help...
Thanks in advance

successful build of nextjs 13 app and successful deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to ur code

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export const fetchCache = "force-no-store";
```

Also I wrote an article giving a quick fix to prerendering error

https://medium.com/phantom3/next-js-14-build-prerender-error-fix-f3c51de2fe1d

Disclosure: I wrote the article

This solution is similar to GetStaticProps() which is not available in next js app router

Comment: thanks a lot. This really solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

using proper next 13 fetch sequence solved the problem for me
you can use fetch(`${api}`, { headers, cache: 'your cache option'})

Answer (score 0):

This error occur because it didn't get the localhost. I think you are fetching data from database by using API calls. If the component is server you should directly use the database function e.g

In `MongoDB` database

`const blog = posts.find({});`

This upper line is used to fetch blogs from database. So you just use this line directly in your component and don't use API call

You can checkout my repository also where I can done the same thing.

Reference: https://github.com/Kannu-Mandora/my-blogs

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am actually using the .env to load the base url , you can check it in the utility folder .

Comment: updated the process.env.VERCEL_URL variable still it shows the same error `Failed to parse URL from personal-portfolio-k4pobapqy-sahilkhalidsolkar.vercel.app/api/author
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7004:19)
    at r (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/971.js:7149:65)`