`TypeError: fetch failed` when building Next.js 14 app which uses app router and Flask for backend
I am trying to build my Next.js 14 app and get the following error:
Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (0/6)  [=   ]TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async f (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14305)
    at async g (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14454) {
  cause: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  },
  digest: '4057488120'
}
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async f (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14305)
    at async g (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14454) {
  cause: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  },
  digest: '4057488120'
}
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async f (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14305)
    at async g (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14454) {
  cause: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  },
  digest: '4057488120'
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/dashboard". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12618:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async f (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14305)
    at async g (MY_FOLDERclient\.next\server\app\dashboard\page.js:24:14454)
 ✓ Generating static pages (6/6)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /dashboard/page: /dashboard

I know it's because the server is not running but if I am building this in gitlab, where I have put Next.js/client and Flask/server to different repos, there is no way to building them simultaneously.
So what is the actual solution to this? FYI I am using app folder in my Next.js app.
This is a piece of "src\app\dashboard\page.tsx":
import { getData } from "@/lib/getData";

export default async function Dashboard() {
  const assets = { ... };
  const baseCurrency = "EUR";
  const data = await getData(assets, baseCurrency);
  ...

and
"src\lib\getData.ts":
import { PortfolioData } from "./definitions";

export async function getData(
  assets: Record<string, any>,
  baseCurrency: string
): Promise<PortfolioData> {
  const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ assets, baseCurrency }),
    cache: "no-cache",
  };

  const res = await fetch(
    "http://localhost:8080/api/portfolio",
    requestOptions
  );

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch portfolio data");
  }

  return res.json();
}

I didn't manage to try anything as it is all so confusing.

I am also getting the same issue while running next build. Have you found any solution for this?

Yes I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76504512/while-building-the-next-js-13-app-it-gives-fetch-failed-error-and-also-prerender/77507845
